# Check if all the values in array of object is equal to false and return true in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am trying to check if all the objects in an array is equal to false ,if yes then return true in react. my array of objects looks like bellow

```
[{"filter":"ASIA","key":0,"isChecked":false},{"filter":"INDIA","key":1,"isChecked":false},{"filter":"MANDYA","key":2,"isChecked":false},{"filter":"GOA","key":3,"isChecked":false},{"filter":"KERALA","key":4,"isChecked":false}]
```

I have tried bellow code using both **every** and **some**:

```
let check = arr.some(element => element.isChecked === false);
```

and

```
let check = arr.every(element => element.isChecked === false);
```

both the above statements returns false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`let check = arr.every(element => element.isChecked === false);` should be correct. You want to check and assert that *every* element in the array meets a condition.

It could be simplified a bit to `arr.every(({ isChecked }) => !isChecked);` since `isChecked` is already a boolean value.

```js
const arr = [{"filter":"ASIA","key":0,"isChecked":false},{"filter":"INDIA","key":1,"isChecked":false},{"filter":"MANDYA","key":2,"isChecked":false},{"filter":"GOA","key":3,"isChecked":false},{"filter":"KERALA","key":4,"isChecked":false}];

const check = arr.every(({ isChecked }) => !isChecked);

console.log(check);
```